# Pass Javascript Variable to Django Views

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

I am a beginner in `Django` and wrote a script code but i am not able to pass the variable to django `views.py`

```
var selectedDataSet = new String('test');
function getDataSet() {
  var dataSetList = document.querySelector('#list');
  selectedDataSet = dataSetList.options[dataSetList.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(selectedDataSet)
  return selectedDataSet;
}
```

this is working perfectly, but i dont know how to pass selectedDataSet to Django views.py.

Comment: you can pass data to your server only via form submission or via AJAX

Comment: so should i call selectedDataSet on a form input? Will that work?

Comment: No. You need to create a jQuery function that will send JSON data to your server upon form submission. In your django view, you need to capture this data if you want to process it.